# How to access library’s symbol table, to find the routine symbol names

Tags: debug-symbols, nm, symbol-table, dumpbin

I need to identify the addresses of the crypto routines used in a linux executable that links to the OpenSSL library. How can I access the openssl symbol table?

```
address    routine name
4099bc0    BF_cbc_encrypt()
40e4463    bf_cbc_cipher()
```

How to retrive above sort of information from openssl cyptolib?

can anyone help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: What kind of executable is it?  Windows, Linux, Mac, ...?

Comment: On Linux, use [nm](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+nm+site:stackoverflow.com) or [readelf](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+readelf+site:stackoverflow.com). You might also be able to use [objdump](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+objdump+site:stackoverflow.com). On Windows, use [dumpbin](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+dumpbin+site:stackoverflow.com) or a PE viewer like [PEBrowse](http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/pebrowse-pro-file-viewer.html).